# Create Enum from Name in PHP

Tags: php, enums

In PHP 8.1, [BackedEnum](https://www.php.net/manual/de/language.enumerations.backed.php) offer a `from` and `tryFrom` method to get an enum from a value. How can the same be achieved by non backed enums?

Example BackedEnum:

```
enum MainType: string
{
    case Full = 'a';
    case Major = 'b';
    case Minor = 'c';
}

var_dump(MainType::tryFrom('a')); // MainType::Full
var_dump(MainType::tryFrom('d')); // null
```

However this doesn't exist for regular enums.

How would I retrieve a "normal" Enum by name, like:

```
enum MainType
{
    case Full;
    case Major;
    case Minor;
}

$name = (MainType::Full)->name
var_dump(name); // (string) Full
```

One option I've found is to simply add a `tryFromName` function, accepting a string and looping over all the cases like this:

```
enum MainType
{
    case Full;
    case Major;
    case Minor;

    public static function tryFromName(string $name): ?static
    {
        foreach (static::cases() as $case) {
            if ($case->name === $name) {
                return $case;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}

$name = (MainType::Full)->name
var_dump(name); // (string) Full
var_dump(MainType::tryFromName($name)); // MainType::Full
```

This works, however it seams counter intuitive to enable a foreach loop going over all possibilities just to create an enum.

Therefore the question is, what is the right way to get an Enum in PHP from the name.

Comment: Are you looking for `var_dump(constant("MainType::$name"));` which will show `enum(MainType::Full)` if `$name = "Full"`.

Comment: I've just tried it and while it works, it requires the full name of the class, like "App\\Config\\MainType", which is fine, however when `$name` is set to something not existing an error is thrown instead of the `null` I want. I could wrap the whole call in a try/catch block but is that any better than simply looping over a hand full of values?

Comment: Yea the error is by design. Starting to sound like a [x/y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If you're not sure if the enum exist, why use enum's in the first place? Maybe you could give a real-world example why you need something like this?

Comment: Sure @0stone0 in my case I'm using the EnumType of Symfony Form and in one case the selected value can be set by a optional get parameter. In my case I simply cast the parameter to string, have a default value of `'none'` and if it's not set (or invalid) I just want a `null`

Comment: Worth mentioning that it is not a good practise to leak app-related names (i.e. case names) outside (e.g. into HTML) and use it as a value. It's what **the Enum value** is designed for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I love the use of `ReflectionEnum` in [@hejdav's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72548657/352040) and it works PHP8.1+, and this would be my preference.

Unfortunately it fails Phpstan tests saying `Method EnumClass::tryFromName() should return EnumClass|null but returns UnitEnum|null.`, so I resorted to using the following:

```php
trait EnumFromName
{
    /**
     * To mirror backed enums tryFrom - returns null on failed match.
     */
    public static function tryFromName(string $name): ?static
    {
        foreach (self::cases() as $case) {
            if ($case->name === $name) {
                return $case;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * To mirror backed enums from - throws ValueError on failed match.
     */
    public static function fromName(string $name): static
    {
        $case = self::tryFromName($name);
        if (! $case) {
            throw new ValueError($name.' is not a valid case for enum '.self::class);
        }

        return $case;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use Reflection:

```php
trait Enum {

    public static function tryFromName(string $name): ?static
    {
        $reflection = new ReflectionEnum(static::class);

        return $reflection->hasCase($name)
            ? $reflection->getCase($name)->getValue()
            : null;
    }

}

enum Foo {
    use Enum;

    case ONE;
    case TWO;
}

var_dump( Foo::tryFromName('TWO')   ); // enum(Foo::TWO)
var_dump( Foo::tryFromName('THREE') ); // null
```

Works also for Backed Enums.